# sum of 100 terms of logarithmic expression

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Calculate value of

> $\displaystyle \sum^{100}_{k=1}\ln\bigg(\frac{(2k+1)^4+\frac{1}{4}}{16k^4+\frac{1}{4}}\bigg)$

My try :: $\displaystyle x^4+4y^4$

$=(x^2+2xy+2y^2)(x^2-2xy+2y^2)$

So sum $\displaystyle \sum^{100}_{k=1}\ln\bigg(\frac{1+4(2k+1)^4}{1+4(2k)^4}\bigg)$

$\displaystyle =\sum^{100}_{k=1}\ln\bigg[\frac{(1+2(2k+1)+2(2k+1)^2)(1-2(2k+1)+2(2k+1)^2)}{(1+2(2k)+2(2k)^2)(1-2(2k)+2(2k)^2)}\bigg]$

How can I decompose that complex expression into partial fractions?

Comment: In these type of complex expressions, always first try to break it into smaller pieces to make the calculation easier. Otherwise the expression eventually becomes even bigger to calculate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$g(k)=\dfrac{(2k+1)^4+\dfrac14}{(2k)^4+\dfrac14}=\dfrac{(4k+2)^4+4\cdot1^4}{(4k)^4+4\cdot1^4}$$

Using your formula only,

$\displaystyle x^4+4y^4=(x^2+2y^2)^2-(2xy)^2=(x^2+2xy+2y^2)(x^2-2xy+2y^2)$

$x=4k+2, y=1$

$\displaystyle\implies x^2+2xy+2y^2=(4k+2)^2+2(4k+2)+2=16k^2+24k+10\  \ \ \ (1)$

$x^2-2xy+2y^2=(4k+2)^2-2(4k+2)+2=16k^2+8k+2\  \ \ \ (2)$

$x=4k, y=1$

$\displaystyle\implies x^2+2xy+2y^2=(4k)^2+2(4k)+2=?\  \ \ \ (3)$ which cancels $(2)$

$\displaystyle\implies x^2-2xy+2y^2=(4k)^2-2(4k)+2=16k^2-8k+2=(4k-2)^2+2(4k-2)+2\  \ \ \ (4)$

$$\implies\prod_{k=1}^n\dfrac{(2k+1)^4+\dfrac14}{(2k)^4+\dfrac14}=\prod_{k=1}^n\dfrac{(4k+2)^2+2(4k+2)+2}{(4(k-1)+2)^2+2(4(k-1)+2)+2}=\prod_{k=1}^n\dfrac{f(k)}{f(k-1)}$$  where $f(m)=(4m+2)^2+2(4m+2)+2$

$$\implies\prod_{k=1}^n\dfrac{(2k+1)^4+\dfrac14}{(2k)^4+\dfrac14}=\dfrac{f(n)}{f(0)}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\ln (16241)$. Work out the first few cases, use $\ln a + \ln b = \ln ab$ and then prove by induction.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do bit by bit.
$$\frac{(2k+1)^4+\frac{1}{4}}{16k^4+\frac{1}{4}}$$
$$=\frac{(k+\frac{1}{2})^4+\frac{1}{64}}{k^4+\frac{1}{64}}$$
Now,
$$\ln\Big( \frac{(k+\frac{1}{2})^4+\frac{1}{64}}{k^4+\frac{1}{64}} \Big)$$
$$=\ln\Big( (k+\frac{1}{2})^4+\frac{1}{64} \Big)-\ln\Big( k^4+\frac{1}{64} \Big)$$

Now bring the summation.
$$\sum^{100}_{k=1} \ln\Big( (k+\frac{1}{2})^4+\frac{1}{64} \Big)-\ln\Big( k^4+\frac{1}{64} \Big)$$

$$=\Big[\ln\Big( (1+\frac{1}{2})^4+\frac{1}{64} \Big) - \ln\Big( 1^4+\frac{1}{64} \Big)\Big] + \Big[ \ln\Big( (2+\frac{1}{2})^4+\frac{1}{64} \Big) - \ln\Big( 2^4+\frac{1}{64} \Big) \Big] + \Big[ \ln\Big( (3+\frac{1}{2})^4+\frac{1}{64} \Big) - \ln\Big( 3^4+\frac{1}{64} \Big) \Big] + \dots + \Big[ \ln\Big( (100+\frac{1}{2})^4+\frac{1}{64} \Big) - \ln\Big( 100^4+\frac{1}{64} \Big) \Big]$$

Hope you can continue after this as it's now simplified